# Authenticating to Trello API using RestSharp

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth, restsharp, trello

I'm struggling a bit to figure out how to use Trello's OAuth API calls from my Windows Phone 7 app. The API isn't really documented, aside from a [listing of the endpoints](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#getting-a-token-from-a-user).

Here's what I have so far:

```
public void OnAuthenticateClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string consumerKey = "mykey";
    const string consumerSecret = "mysecret";
    const string baseUrl = "https://trello.com/1";

    var client = new RestClient(baseUrl) 
    {
        Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
    };
    var request = new RestRequest("OAuthGetRequestToken", Method.POST);
    var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request, HandleResponse);
}

private void HandleResponse(IRestResponse restResponse)
{
    var response = restResponse;
    Console.Write(response.StatusCode);
}
```

I'm getting a `404` response, so something's not right, obviously.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Does it work if you aren't using ExecuteAsync (e.g. `IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);`)?  That makes the first step (the `OauthGetRequestToken` bit) work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Not using the `ExecuteAsync` seems to make it work:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("OAuthGetRequestToken", Method.POST);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.Write(response.StatusCode);
```

At one point "oAuth1 is not yet supported in async scenarios (SL and WP)", according to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/restsharp/browse_thread/thread/2e8788f2c36cedc9) by John Sheehan.

Comment: Interesting observation. Thanks for trying that out. Unfortunately, Windows Phone only supports asynchronous calls. But this does give me a vector for investigation.

Comment: @JoshEarl It seems that at one point async wasn't supported for OAuth 1.0, I'm not sure if that's still true.

Answer (score 2):

I think your base url is incorrect. 
Please try the following:

const string baseUrl = "https://api.trello.com/1";

Answer (score 1):

Replace OAuthGetRequestToken with authorize.

Comment: Thanks for the response, John. Tried that out, but I'm still getting a `404`. When I used `OAuthGetRequestToken` the `RequestUri` was properly formed, pointing to https://trello.com/1/https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken, which seems right. I'm trying to puzzle this out from the RestSharp integration tests, but it's not obvious how to map what you're doing there to the Trello calls.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see the OAuth URL section when I was on my phone. The non-oauth version looks simpler almost. Have you considered using that instead?

Comment: Good suggestion. This turns out to be pretty simple to implement, although I'm not crazy about parsing the token out of the HTML response. Seems fragile. Long term, OAuth seems like the "right" way to go, but for now I'll take the simpler path.